# Replace variable from script to another on the same page (JS/PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, replace, jwplayer

I have this script generated by wordpress plugin:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
if (typeof(jQuery)=="function") {
    (function($) {
        $.fn.fitVids=function(){}})(jQuery)
};
jwplayer('jwplayer-0').setup({
    "aspectratio":null,
    "width":604,
    "height":410,
    "skin":"beelden",
    "primary":"html5",
    "advertising":{
        "client":"vast",
        "tag":"http://vasttag"
    },
    "sharing":{},
    "image":"http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/image/0.jpg",
    "file":"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hgfakjhs"
});
</script>
```

I simply want add this line:

```
,"position":"post"
```

after:

```
"http://vasttag"
```

I can't edit the plugin, so is there a way to do it with javascript?

Sorry for my bad english.

Please help me!

Thanks!

Edit: This is the plugin file that generates the player:
[link](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aTSVgkWZxuuIJ%3atedi.co:81/netdesain/cstar-design/blob/502876a2b4a50567cfca95ca8c32690569f6bea2/wp-content/plugins/jw-player-plugin-for-wordpress/jwp6/jwp6-class-player.php+&cd=1&hl=it&ct=clnk&gl=it)

if anyone knows how to add that parameter I would be very grateful :)

Edit 2:
I solved adding that parameter directly in the database, in wp-option table at jwp6_player_config_2 option name. If you know better solution let me know, thanks.

Comment: You'd probably be better off asking this in the jwplayer forum at www.longtailvideo.com

Comment: i think `jwplayer` or `jwplayer.setup` return object with players, so you can manualy set property what you want

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you can do that using javascript.We generally use javascript to do changes in DOM and not in javascript itself.You can do one thing that you create.

```
<script>
 if(typeof(jQuery)=="function")
 {
 (function($){$.fn.fitVids=function(){}})(jQuery)};

jwplayer('jwplayer-0').setup({"aspectratio":null,"width":604,"height":410,"skin":"beelden","primary":"html5","advertising":{"client":"vast",,"position":"post","tag":"http://vasttag"},"sharing":{},"image":"http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/image/0.jpg","file":"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hgfakjhs"});
        </script>
```

and append it somewhere in DOM using javascript or jquery.

More better solution: Just edit the script added by plugin.It is the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

Due to what the script does (it creates a new jwPlayer as soon as the script is encountered) and the fact that there seems to be no method in the jwPlayer API to edit a players settings, it is impossible to change your script as you want.
The only solution is to edit the script at its source.

Comment: thanks, i added the source if you can do something... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can always do is use our JavaScript API - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28851/javascript-api-reference

To make the VAST tag play after the video is complete. Just put this script block after the shortcode on your post:

```
<script>
jwplayer().onComplete(function(){jwplayer().playAd('your_ad_tag');});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Ethan, but now i get this error: 
There was an error calling back an event handler jwplayer.js?ver=3.6.1:3
This is the website: [notizie di cronaca](http://notizie-di-cronaca.info/il-gatto-squalo-pulisce-la-cucina/)

Comment: Hm, can I see where this is being run?

Comment: Wait 10 seconds than click on "guarda il video" under the player on the right :)

Comment: I did, but nothing. Can you put up a test page?